# Make JwPlayer Always Play at Last 5 seconds Section of Video Which Being Recorded in Append Mode

Tags: html, video, streaming, jwplayer, red5

Assuming we record some video from media server in `Append` mode.

How do We make `JwPlayer` (or another video player) seek and play to always (Let's said) last 5 seconds of Video which being recorded?

Thanks,

Comment: You could use our api and seek. first you would have to get the duration, then seek to the duration minus 5. Not super trivial, but can be done via the js api - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

Comment: but still the video which being appended can't be played. Could JwPlayer play a video without file extension? (eg. myvideo), or video with undefined extensions (eg. myvideo.flv.ser)?

Comment: You can play a video without a file extension, but some additional information (variables) need to be added to the setup. For example, i JW5, set the "provider" variable to "video". In JW6, set the "type" variable to "mp4" (that is assuming the file without the extension is indeed an mp4 file).